# Android + phonegap +package manager

Tags: javascript, android, cordova-2.0.0

I need to write a cordova plugin to retrive the application name, version code and version name using for Android application. Please Respond ASAP... Thanks in Advance :)

Here is my Code....getting Invalid Action Error Message.

In **My.js**

```
var AppInfo = function() {};
AppInfo.prototype.getVersionName = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return cordova.exec(
        successCallback, 
        failureCallback, 
        'AppInfo', 
        'GetVersionName', 
        []
    );
};
```

In **AppInfo.java** *(Plugin)*

```
package com.cordova.plugin.appInfo;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;

public class AppInfo extends CordovaPlugin {
public final String ACTION_GET_VERSION_NAME = "GetVersionName";
Context ctx;
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
    ctx = cordova.getContext();
    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
    PackageManager packageManager = this.ctx.getPackageManager();
    if(action.equals(ACTION_GET_VERSION_NAME)) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                                          this.ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
            result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, packageInfo.versionName);
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
            result = new PluginResult(Status.ERROR, nnfe.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

In **.html**

```
<script>
function onDeviceReady () {
    $('#send').bind('click', function () {
        alert('Hello World'); 
        window.applicationInfo = new AppInfo();
        window.applicationInfo.getVersionName( function(versionName){
           alert("versionName" + versionName);
        },
        function (errorMessage){
           alert("Error is "+errorMessage);
        }
        ); 
    });                
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
```

and finally setting permission and Plugin in plugin.xml

Answer (score 2):

This helper function retrieves all installed apps with the application name, package name, version-number and -code as well as the icons. The method `getPackages()` returns an `ArrayList` with all the apps.

> ```
> class PInfo {
> private String appname = "";
> private String pname = "";
> private String versionName = "";
> private int versionCode = 0;
> private Drawable icon;
> private void prettyPrint() {
>     Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
> }
>  }
> private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
>     ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
>    final int max = apps.size();
>     for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
>        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
>    }
>   return apps;
>    }       
>
> private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
>       ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
>      List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
>       for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
>              PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
>              if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
>               continue ;
>        }
>     PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
>     newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
>     newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
>     newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
>     newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
>     newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
>     res.add(newInfo);
> }
> return res; 
>  }
> ```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, please correct me if m wrong...the code u posted will be helpful to me later...first i need to write a phonegap plugin to get the Version name etc.

Comment: I am trying to implement the same functionality. Any luck with this? Kindly update

Answer (score 1):

You can write plugin for the Package Manager by extending PhoneGap's Plugin class and add package Info class there in Plugin and implement logic to get installed applications.

Comment: Thank you!! thats wat m looking for...and getting issues with the same..thnxx for the reply :)