# Invalid Action Error in phonegap SMS plugin

Tags: android, cordova, sms, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a SMS plugin for phonegap in Android. I am getting an invalid action error when I am trying to send the message. I have looked at [Android + phonegap +package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682818/android-phonegap-package-manager). My problem is the same but any answer in the link does not help.

This is my .js file.

```
 var SmsPlugin = function () {};

SmsPlugin.prototype.send = function (phone, message, successCallback, failureCallback) {    
    return cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', "SendSMS", [phone, message]);
};

window.sms = new SmsPlugin();
```

And following is my .java file

```
package com.*.PhonegapSMSDPN;

import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

public class SmsPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public final String ACTION_SEND_SMS = "SendSMS";

    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray arg1, String callbackId) {
        Toast.makeText(this.cordova.getActivity(), action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        Log.e("msg", action);
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_SMS)) {
            try {
                String phoneNumber = arg1.getString(0);
                String message = arg1.getString(1);
                sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
                result = new PluginResult(Status.OK);
            }
            catch (JSONException ex) {
                result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, ex.getMessage());
                Log.e("error", result+" ");
            }           
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.cordova.getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);  

        manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
    }

}
```

I have made necessary changes in config.xml file too.
Please guide me in solving the problem.Thanks

PS-i am using Phonegap2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Your js file is missing some code. I have implemented a sms plugin in phonegap too and here is my working js code. You should customize the plugin path.

```
var SmsPlugin = function() {};

SmsPlugin.prototype.send = function(phone, message, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', "SendSMS", [phone, message]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("sms", new SmsPlugin());
});

cordova.define("app/scripts/vendor/smsplugin", function (require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');
    var SmsPlugin = function () {};

    /**
     * Check if the device has a possibility to send and receive SMS
     */
    SmsPlugin.prototype.isSupported = function (successCallback, failureCallback) {
        return exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', 'HasSMSPossibility', []);
    }
    /**
     * Send a message to the given phone number
     */
    SmsPlugin.prototype.send = function (phone, message, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        return exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', 'SendSMS', [phone, message]);
    }

    var smsplugin = new SmsPlugin();
        module.exports = smsplugin;
});
```